# 4th level indent in table of contents in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I discovered that the number of heading levels showed in the TOC can be changed, but I can't figure out how to increase the indent for the 4th level and beyond -- it has the same indent as the 3rd level, which is no different than having it as a 3rd level heading. Is there a way to make the 4th level and beyond indent more, as they should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about styles. Word has built-in styles for TOC levels that you can modify. TOC 4 is the style you want to tweak. After you get it the way you want, regenerate the TOC.

Comment: I don't think you need to regenerate the TOC just to apply the style changes. Styles make all styled text change instantly.

Comment: true enough. i just have a habit of regenerating to make sure the TOC is going to behave properly the next time it's updated.

Answer (score 6):

When you create the table of contents, choose Custom Table of Contents.

[image]

Then under Show Levels, select 4

[image]

Comment: They already *have* four levels; it's just that the fourth level isn't tyled the way they want.